# How to separate MVC folders out of application directory in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm very new at codeigniter.  I was just wondering if there is anyway that I can separate the **controllers**, **models**, and **views** folders out of the application folder or put them in a sub-directory.

I understand it's not crucial but it would be easier to find when it's **just these three** folders in a separate folder.

For example the structure could be as a sub-directory: 
-> application 
   -> **MVC** 
      -> controllers 
 
      -> models 
      -> views 
   -> ...

My question is if there is a way, what configuration would I have to change in order to make the move?

Thank you!

Comment: They are already all in one folder ... the application folder.

Comment: what will be the advantage of moving them into a sub folder ?

Comment: David, I clarified my quesiton.  Umair, I just think they would be easier to find.  Granted, it's mostly 10 seconds of searching, it would just be faster if just these three are in one folder.

Comment: Firstly, you shouldn't use CI for production ready apps.. I won't begin to get into that. However, you should look into the hmvc library by wiredesignz for CI.. it applies the concept of packaged MVCs that are "all inclusive and self running".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hierarchical model–view–controller (HMVC) is a software architectural pattern, a variation of Model–view–controller (MVC) similar to Presentation-abstraction-control (PAC)，[more info in wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMVC)
I hope you have enjoyed [this tutorial](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/hvmc-an-introduction-and-application/).

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you use links placed in the directory you desire pointing to the folders in the application folder. I wouldn't recommend moving those folders out of the application folder.

Cheers.